GitLab deploy a NuGet package to realease page
I am trying to create a release and upload a package file using a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. The pipeline runs on a Docker executor using the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 image. I have a shell script (create_release.sh) that performs the following steps:

Prints the CI_PROJECT_ID.
Prints the API endpoint URL.
Gets the latest package file and extracts the version.
Sets the authorization header.
Makes a curl request to create the release.
Uploads the package file to the release.

Here is the content of the create_release.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

# Print the CI_PROJECT_ID
echo "CI_PROJECT_ID $CI_PROJECT_ID"

# Print the API endpoint URL
echo "https://example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/releases"

# Get the latest package file and extract the version
PACKAGE_FILE=$(ls nupkg/*.nupkg | sort -V | tail -n1)
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(basename "$PACKAGE_FILE" .nupkg | awk -F. "{print \$NF}")

# Set the authorization header
AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: Bearer $CI_JOB_TOKEN"

# Make the curl request to create the release
curl --header "$AUTH_HEADER" \
     --request POST \
     --form "tag_name=$PACKAGE_VERSION" \
     --form "name=Release $PACKAGE_VERSION" \
     --form "description=Initial release" \
     "https://example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/releases" \
     --fail -v

# Upload the package file to the release
curl --header "$AUTH_HEADER" \
     --request POST \
     --form "file=@$PACKAGE_FILE" \
     --form "name=$(basename "$PACKAGE_FILE")" \
     "https://example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/releases/$PACKAGE_VERSION/assets/uploads" \
     --fail -v

The .gitlab-ci.yml file is configured to run this script:
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_release:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - chmod +x create_release.sh
    - ./create_release.sh

However, the pipeline fails with the following logs:
Running with gitlab-runner 17.6.0 (374d34fd)
  on gitlab-runner-autoscale01 t1_QP87cb, system ID: r_wwk8gZaMezpD
Resolving secrets
Preparing the "docker-autoscaler" executor 00:12
Dialing instance gitlab-runner-autoscale01-43cf6e2d-409d-4942-92c8-7581d7f346b6...
Instance gitlab-runner-autoscale01-43cf6e2d-409d-4942-92c8-7581d7f346b6 connected
Using Docker executor with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 ...
Pulling docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 ...
Using docker image sha256:70d4f0c5224df68db203a761ced0857bef488bde1f5d8cecd7d543f0d5b82be0 for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 with digest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:f91f9181d68b5ed2c8dea199dbbd2f6d172e60bdc43f8a67878b1ad140cf8d6b ...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner-t1qp87cb-project-18766-concurrent-0 via 51c9ecf0e69b...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/xxxxx/package-name/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out a7b9becc as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts 00:01
Downloading artifacts for package-job (694982)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        host=example.com id=694982 responseStatus=200 OK token=glcbt-64
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00
Using docker image sha256:70d4f0c5224df68db203a761ced0857bef488bde1f5d8cecd7d543f0d5b82be0 for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 with digest mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:f91f9181d68b5ed2c8dea199dbbd2f6d172e60bdc43f8a67878b1ad140cf8d6b ...
$ chmod +x create_release.sh
$ ./create_release.sh
CI_PROJECT_ID 18766
https://example.com/api/v4/projects/18766/releases
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 185.149.214.17:443...
* Connected to example.com (185.149.214.17) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5341 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [520 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=DE; ST= rhein- falen; O= ; CN=example.com
*  start date: Jul 23 00:00:00 2024 UTM
*  expire date: Jul 23 23:59:59 2025 UTM
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=NL; O=GEANT Vereniging; CN=GEANT OV RSA CA 4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
* using HTTP/2
* h2h3 [:method: POST]
* h2h3 [:path: /api/v4/projects/18766/releases]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: example.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.88.1]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* h2h3 [authorization: Bearer [MASKED]]
* h2h3 [content-length: 361]
* h2h3 [content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------cd886831b6fdf250]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f41c28ece0)
} [5 bytes data]
> POST /api/v4/projects/18766/releases HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.88.1
> accept: */*
> authorization: Bearer [MASKED]
> content-length: 361
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------cd886831b6fdf250
> 
} [5 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 422 
< server: nginx
< date: Mon, 02 Dec 2024 14:39:00 UTM
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 34
< cache-control: no-cache
< vary: Origin
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-gitlab-meta: {"correlation_id":"01JE3WYXKPQGCGWVB0QA9HCNBJ","version":"1"}
< x-request-id: 01JE3WYXKPQGCGWVB0QA9HCNBJ
< x-runtime: 0.094993
< strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
* The requested URL returned error: 422
 91   395    0     0  100   361      0   2791 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2798
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 422
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 185.149.214.17:443...
* Connected to example.com (185.149.214.17) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5341 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [520 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=DE; ST= rhein- falen; O= ; CN=example.com
*  start date: Jul 23 00:00:00 2024 UTM
*  expire date: Jul 23 23:59:59 2025 UTM
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=NL; O=GEANT Vereniging; CN=GEANT OV RSA CA 4
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
* using HTTP/2
* h2h3 [:method: POST]
* h2h3 [:path: /api/v4/projects/18766/releases/0/assets/uploads]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: example.com]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.88.1]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* h2h3 [authorization: Bearer [MASKED]]
* h2h3 [content-length: 48627]
* h2h3 [content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------03c359419497f059]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f78d950ce0)
} [5 bytes data]
> POST /api/v4/projects/18766/releases/0/assets/uploads HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.88.1
> accept: */*
> authorization: Bearer [MASKED]
> content-length: 48627
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------03c359419497f059
> 
} [5 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 404 
< server: nginx
< date: Mon, 02 Dec 2024 14:39:00 UTM
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 25
< cache-control: no-cache
< vary: Origin
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-gitlab-meta: {"correlation_id":"01JE3WYXRFM2SCWNDFPYZBA5T1","version":"1"}
< x-request-id: 01JE3WYXRFM2SCWNDFPYZBA5T1
< x-runtime: 0.015351
< strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
* The requested URL returned error: 404
100 48652    0     0  100 48627      0   742k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  753k
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

The first curl request to create the release returns a 422 Unprocessable Entity error, and the second curl request to upload the package file returns a 404 Not Found error.
I have verified that the CI_PROJECT_ID and CI_JOB_TOKEN are correct and have the necessary permissions. The API endpoint https://example.com/api/v4/projects/18766/releases is accessible via a browser.
What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve them?
